# Can I represent a given word (String) as a number?

Tags: c#, .net, string, character-encoding, numbers

Suppose I have a list of words e.g.

```
var words = new [] {"bob", "alice", "john"};
```

Is there a way to represent each of those words as numbers so that one could use such numbers to sort the words.

One use-case which I think this can be used for is to use *Counting Sort* to sort a list of words. Again I am only interested in whether this is at all possible not that it may not be the most efficient way to sort a list of words.

Do note this is not about hash-codes or different sorting algorithms. I am curious to find out if a string can be represented as a number.

Comment: Yes. Use the index in the array.  Calculate some number, somehow. Use ToHashCode() wich gives you an int. Will you be able to get the word if I give you a number? Doubt so, unless we use the same encoding. Enven so, Collisions might happen. This is quite opinionated and prone to discussions, so no good fit for SO Q&A format. Voting to close.

Comment: Well string can certainly be represented by a number, as well as any other information. For example: new BigInteger(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some string")) gives you such number.

Comment: Strings are already numbers under the hood, a processor doesn't know beans about strings.  The CLR is heavily micro-optimized to make strings as efficient as possible, they left no stone unturned.  And important, programs use strings a lot and you can't create a good web server if string perf is poor.  Cooking up your own flavor of it is quite unlikely to beat it.

Comment: @HansPassant, agreed and upvoted, I am not trying to build a string replacement, I am merely interested to see whether I can use a mathematical function to convert a string to an integer for the purpose of sorting using _Counting Sort_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary instead of an array.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> words = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        words.Add(0, "bob");
        words.Add(1, "alice");
        words.Add(2, "john");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> word in words.OrderBy(w => w.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

NOTE: It's better to work with collections in place of arrays is easier to use for most developers.

Comment: By the way, you can just use `.Add(key, value) ` on the dictionary object. You don't have to create a key value pair first.

Comment: An object initializer is nice too: `new Dictionary<int, string> { { 0, "bob" }, { 1, "alice" }, { 2, "john" }}`. You can format it one pair per line for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the down votes but hey this is what I have come up with so far:

```
private int _alphabetLength = char.MaxValue - char.MinValue;
private BigInteger Convert(string data)
{
    var value = new BigInteger();
    var startPoint = data.Length - 1;
    for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var character = data[i];
        var charNumericValue = character;
        var exponentialWeight = startPoint - i;
        var weightedValue = new BigInteger(charNumericValue * Math.Pow(_alphabetLength, exponentialWeight));
        value += weightedValue;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Using the above to convert the following:

```
var words = new [] {"bob", "alice", "john" };
```

- 420901224533 // bob
- -9223372036854775808 // alice
- 29835458486206476 // john

Despite the overflow the output looks sorted to me, I need to improve this and test it properly but at least it is a start.

Comment: You're missing `if (data.Length > 2) throw new ArgumentException("lengths greater than 2 exceed the size of long.");` but before that try `Debug.Assert(Convert("bobbob") != Convert("alice"), "Collision");`

Comment: @TomBlodget Easily fixed...sort of!